# Element where all valuations are zero

Tags: commutative-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, valuation-theory

I am studying valuation theory at the moment and I came across this question:

Let $K$ be a field and let $a \in K$ such that $v(a) = 0$ for every valuation $v$ on $K$. What can we say about $a$?

In the positive characteristic case, for instance, we have the following:

**Remark 1:** Assume that $K$ has characteristic $p > 0$ and let $\mathbb F_p$ denote its prime field. Let $a \in K$. Then $v(a) = 0$ for every valuation $v$ on $K$ if and only if $a$ is algebraic over $\mathbb F_p$.

*Proof of Remark 1:* Assume first that $a$ is not algebraic over $\mathbb F_p$. Then $a$ is an irreducible element in the polynomial ring $\mathbb F_p[a]$ and hence induces a discrete rank-one valuation $w$ on its quotient field $\mathbb F_p(a)$ with $w(a) = 1$. This valuation $w$ extends to a valuation $v$ on $K$, because $\mathbb F_p(a) \subseteq K$. In particular, $v(a) = 1 \neq 0$. Now assume that $a$ is algebraic over $\mathbb F_p$. Then, clearly, $\mathbb F_p(a)$ is a finite field. It is well-known that finite fields do only admit the trivial valuation with constant value $0$. If now $v$ is a valuation on $K$, then $v$ restricted to $\mathbb F_p(a)$ is constant $0$ and in particular $v(a) = 0$, which ends the proof.

The first part of the above proof can be used to show also the following:

**Remark 2:** Let $K$ be any field and let $a \in K$ be transcendental over the prime field of $K$. Then there exists a valuation $v$ on $K$ such that $v(a) \neq 0$.

**Example:** If $K = \mathbb Q$ then by using $p$-adic valuations it is clear that there exists a valuation $v$ on $K$ with $v(a) \neq 0$ unless $a \in \{1,-1\}$.

**Question:** Let $K$ be of characteristic $0$ and let $a \in K$ be algebraic over $\mathbb Q$. What can we say about $a$?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: If $v(a)=0$ for every valuation $v$ on $K$, then $a \in O_K^{\times}$ ie $a,1/a$ are algebraic integers.

Comment: To clarify: We exclude archimedean values here? Otherwise I would surely have placed a bet on the roots of unity and nothing else (which, by the way, are another way to phrase the answer in positive characteristic as well). Now I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Yeah, only non-archimedean.